# Reset reCaptcha when user fails to tick the box - FormMail and fmbadhandler

Tags: php

When a user fails to complete a required field from my 'Contact' page the error is shown up when the form page reloads showing the highlighted required fields.   However, that doesn't reload reCaptcha and a verification error results if the user thinks the "I'm not a robot" has been completed because the green tick remains.

I'm using formmail and fmbadhandler but I can't see a point where I can force reCaptcha to re-set when the form is reloaded.

How do I get reCaptcha to reload when the user returns to the form page please?

Answer (score 0):

I think recaptcha reloads already on page reload. But if you're using ajax, you can try `grecaptcha.reset();` in javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using Ajax.

Comment: The problem is that the html is integrated with formmail.php and formbadhandler.php; both php elements running into hundreds of lines of code.

I hoped that someone with experience using those form management systems would have found a solution.